# MongoDB db.User.find() vs db.users.find()

Tags: mongodb, strongloop

When I register a user with strongloop API example:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Introduction+to+User+model+authentication

It registers a user which I can get back via MongoDB shell: `db.User.find()`

But when I try to `GET` this via ajax using:

```
http://localhost:7777/api/User
```

Using Express Router:

```
router.route("/User/:id?")
```

I get a different `document` which I can only access through the MongoDB shell through:

```
db.users.find()
```

Now, at least it's case sensitive, but how does the same namespace give me a different resource?

Also `POST`ing this through the same `/api/User` it ends up under `db.users` and not `db.User`

** Update **

I've tried this with other endpoints other than User/user and it seems that I just can't get case sensitive documents via web request, which is very strange, because it is definitely getting the right `api/User` with capital...

Also, I'm using `Mongoose` for the data modelling, maybe there's the fault.

Comment: Can you please provide your user model config (.json) file?

Comment: @ReuvenChacha, thing is, I have not defined any model for `User` or `users`

Comment: there is a default collection in mongodb - users. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-users-collection/

Comment: @HarpreetSingh, thanks, but see the update, I've tried it with a custom endpoint, but same problem, it's as if the the libs I'm using for web ignore the Case, even though I see them Cased in the devconsole...

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Also, that documentation calls it `.users`, while I get that exact information through `db.User.find()`. So that looks like it's neither case sensitive or consistent, because when I do: `do.users.find()` i get a different document

Comment: @TrySpace, I have marked this question link, I will setup strongloop and will get back to you tomorrow. I haven't tried strongloop yet(though I wanted to) but I will try to figure out this issue for you for my own learning :)

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Thanks, And I've used this pt1: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1067725/Part-Building-web-app-using-react-js-express-js and this pt2: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1068287/Part-Building-web-app-using-react-js-express-js-no for the frontend

Comment: @TrySpace did you created "user" model while creating strongloop app or it is "User" default that stronloop creates itself for authentication. bcoz its not showing any users collection in mongodb "db.users" shell but only User collection "db.User". More, i have created a collection friends but i can access it with other case Friends, FRIENDs etc

Comment: @HarpreetSingh are you accessing it through the mongoDB shell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101875/discussion-between-harpreet-singh-and-tryspace).